# Node.js : relative and absolute paths

Tags: node.js

There is something I have trouble with when serving pages (in my case, nodejs).

Let's say I have the following url : `http://localhost:80` which serves a simple html page, but you must be logged in, either way you are redirected to a login page (`http://localhost:80/login`).

That's easy, and everything works fine.
Now let's say I have another url `http://otherdoamin.com/internal/back` that redirects to my server listening on the port 80.

I am having trouble to find what's the best way to manage my server to work on both url.

Here's a code sample just to show the logic :

```
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
 //if user isn't logged, redirect to login
}

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  //if user is logged, redirect to base path (/) which serves an html page
  //else
  //display login.html page
})

app.get('/', checkAuth, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});
```

Let's say now that I have the following case :

I go to `http://localhost:80`, but I am not logged, I am redirected to the login page (`http://localhost:80/login`). Then after logging in, I am redirected back to `http://localhost:80`.

But if I do the following case with my other url (`http://otherdoamin.com/internal/back`), I'll have problems with the paths : if I have absolute paths, the redirection to login will work, but after logging in, I'll have a redirection to `http://otherdoamin.com/` instead of http://otherdoamin.com/internal/back/, which is obvious.

Comment: Are you trying to maintain that their url stays http://otherdoamin.com/internal/back? Like they should be able to login and still see the otherdomain in their url bar? If it's just a pure redirect, this is as simple as setting the proper URL values in your DNS.

Comment: Yeah indeed, I do not have access to that (I am not the one making the redirection), but is that the only way to achieve it?

Comment: The only way your server is going to receive any requests from otherdomain, is one of 2 scenarios. A) There is a URL redirect record present in the dns. B) otherdomain is just a reverseproxy that points to your url.

Comment: Exactly, it's a reverse proxy.

Comment: var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;

Comment: Save the original url and redirect back to it at the end of your route chain.

Comment: Or, you could just set http://otherdoamin.com/internal/back as a base url in the RP

Comment: Actually I was working on my local machine, and a guy decided to make a proxy path so we can access it from the internet. Stupid of me, I have already done that kind of configurations with Varnish few weeks ago. You can add your answer below, I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Set otherdomain.com/internal/back as the base url in the Reverse Proxy Path definition.

Option 2:

Store the fully qualified original request url:

`var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;`

And then use that to redirect;